# how to use static function in header and compare with float array

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote this function:

```
static bool colorIsEmpty(const Color col)
{
    return (col[0] == 0 && col[1] == 0 && col[2] == 0 );
}
```

where Color is simply a  float[3];
the function doesn't work if col[3] are all 0;
but this works:

```
if(col[0] == col[1] == col[2] == 0) {
//gets called
}
```

however gcc gives me warning:

```
    cColorTest.c:212:5: warning: suggest parentheses around 
comparison in operand of ‘==’ [-Wparentheses]
```

so it would be nice if that function works,why it doesn't work?
I mean the function always return false,

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Doesn't build? Doesn't compute what you think is the correct result? Makes your computer explode?

Comment: I suppose the warning irritates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition

```
if(col[0] == col[1] == col[2] == 0) {
```

is parenthesised

```
if(((col[0] == col[1]) == col[2]) == 0) {
```

so if `col[0] == col[1]`, it checks whether `col[2] != 1`, and if `col[0] != col[1]`, it checks whether `col[2] != 0`. I strongly believe that is not what you want.

```
static bool colorIsEmpty(const Color col)
{
    return (col[0] == 0 && col[1] == 0 && col[2] == 0 );
}
```

checks whether all three array elements are 0, and if it doesn't give the expected results, your array elements are not what you expect them to be.

Depending on your application, you might want an approximate test instead of strict equality. Due to the nature of floating point numbers, it is not uncommon that different computations that would mathematically have the same result leads to different results in floating point arithmetic/calculus. Usually the difference is small (but it can also become huge, for example due to [loss of significance/catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)), so often floating point values are compared with a tolerance.

Perhaps replacing the `col[i] == 0` with an approximate zero test, `fabsf(col[i]) < epsilon` is the right strategy for your purposes (appropriate values of `epsilon` depend on the use case).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to silence your compiler, you should add parentheses to force the evaluation order. But your comparaison seems wrong; you can't do it that way. Why don't you use the first form? It is more readable, and it works fine, except that compare floating point with `==` operator is quite unsafe.